# Open the last opened view controller when closing and opening the app

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to be able to close and reopen the same view controller on my app. The reason I want to do this is because I have a "tutorial" scene that I only want to be brought up the first time you open the app. Every other time I want the app to instantly open up the second view controller. Here is my code:

for GameViewController:

```
   UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "View")
```

for GameViewController2:

```
   UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "View")
```

for AppDelegate:

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
    [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let viewCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "View")
    var VC = UIViewController()
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    print(viewCount)
    if viewCount == 0 {
        //FirstView should initiate
        VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First") as! GameViewController
    } else {
        //SecondView should inititate
        VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as! GameViewController2
    }

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.window?.rootViewController = VC


    return true
}
```

The problem is that every single time I open the app, it always starts on my first view controller instead of my second view controller. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would change your process.  Have the game always be the first view controller, and use a pop over to present your tutorial if the key is not present

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code above, you are not calling UserDefaults.synchronize

```
var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(1, forKey:"View")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

In both cases it must be synchronised as this saves changes to disk

**Update:** As noted by @cs4alhaider synchronize() is not needed in Swift 4, so this problem would not occur anymore.

Comment: userDefaults.synchronize() it is not necessary in swift 4 and above

Comment: Thanks, since it was the linchpin of the original question's solution I added a footnote.